# how to continue the program when there is exception while calling feign client api in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, java-8, feign

```
public string prospect(List<ProspectRequest> prospectRequest, String primaryClientId) {
    if(p2p(primaryClientId)=="Success") {
        for(ProspectRequest prospect : prospectRequest) {
            p2p(prospect.getId());
       }
   // rest of code i would like to continue
    }
 }

public string p2p(String id){
crmApi.getProspectId(id);//this is external client api
String message = "Success"; 
return message;
}
```

if p2p(primaryClientId) is failed then I need to stop the entire process .How do i like to continue with  "rest of code i would like to continue".

if the feign client api crmApi.getProspectId is success then the success message is returned and then its a good case.
If the crmApi.getProspectId api gives error then I still need to continue the p2p() program for next set of clients also .How does that work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: BTW == for strings looks very un-javaish. `“succes“.equals(p2p(…))` would make sure it works for non-interned strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to use a try catch finally block

```
  public string prospect(List<ProspectRequest> prospectRequest, String primaryClientId) {
  

    try {
      if(p2p(primaryClientId)=="Success") {
         for(ProspectRequest prospect : prospectRequest) {
            p2p(prospect.getId());
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {}  // Exception can be specified exp. RuntimeException
    finally {
       // rest of code i would like to continue
    }
    }
 }

public string p2p(String id){
crmApi.getProspectId(id);//this is external client api
String message = "Success"; 
return message;
}
```

if you need something out of the first if-block you can put an option (if the if-block fails) in the catch-block. When

```
if(p2p(primaryClientId)=="Success") {
             for(ProspectRequest prospect : prospectRequest) {
                p2p(prospect.getId());
            }
```

throws an checked exception you need to change RuntimeExpection to the superclass Exception

edited:

```
 for(ProspectRequest prospect : prospectRequest) {
      try {
        p2p(prospect.getId());
```

} catch (RuntimeExpection  e) {}
}

Comment: Hey Marlos appreciate your answer .I have one more question - lets say my prospectRequest list has 3 objects in it and i need to perform p2p() operation on each on the object. suppose the second object has encountered and error from the third party client in p2p method .I need to continue with the next object instead if stopping there . How do I tackle this ?

Comment: You can create an second try - catch block around the operation or even only around this operation. I have edited in my orginal answer.